# For What positive values of x ; the below mentioned series is convergent and divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$ \sum \frac{1}{x^{n}+x^{-n}}$$

**My attempt**

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{aligned}
\therefore & u_{n+1}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^{2 n+2}+1} \\
\therefore & \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^{2 n+2}+1} \cdot \frac{x^{2 n}+1}{x^{n}} \\
& \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}}=x \frac{1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2 n}}{x^{2}+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2 n}}
\end{aligned}\\
&  i f x>1 \quad \therefore \quad \frac{1}{x}<1 \quad \therefore \text { when } n \rightarrow \infty,\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2 n} \rightarrow 0
\end{aligned}\\
$$

*What to do next*?

Comment: Think about $u_{n+1}$ in the first form in which you wrote it, and think about comparing it to the series $\sum \frac 1{y^k}$ for suitable $k$, whose convergence properties are well known.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон are u talking about "p series test"...How could I compare it. Sorry, I am not getting

Comment: The series I mention is not a $p$-series. It is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{y^k}$, so it is a geometric series. See Kavi's answer.

Comment: There is a much simpler way than  using ratio test. I gave it in  my answer but someone downvoted it.  Do you understand what I have written?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes sir Indeed! I have not done that.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your attempt you have shown that $\lim \sup \frac {u_{n+1}} {u_n} \leq x \frac {1+0} {x^{2}+0}=\frac  1 x <1$. Hence Ratio Test tells you that the series is convergent for $x>1$. But there is a bettter approach as shown below:

For $x>1$ it is dominated by $\sum \frac 1 {x^{n}}$ which is convergent.

For $0<x<1$ it is dominated by $\sum x^{n}$ which is convergent.

For $x=1$ it is divergent.

Comment: For x < 1 ,it is leading to infty/infty form! how it is coming $x^n$

Comment: @Mr.Green $\frac 1  {a+b}  \leq \frac  1a$ and $\frac 1  {a+b}  \leq \frac 1 b$ for all positive numbers $a$ and $b$ take $a=x^{n}, b=x^{-n}$.

Comment: @Mr.Green For $x<1$, you have $$\frac{1}{x^n+x^{-n}} \leq \frac{1}{x^{-n}} =x^n$$

Comment: for x>1 ; the series will become $\frac{1}{x}$ which is divergent

Comment: No you get $\leq \frac  1 {x^{n}}$ and $\sum \frac  1 {x^{n}}$ is a convergent geometric series.

Comment: @Mr.Green For $x>1$, you have $$\frac{1}{x^n + x^{-n}} \leq \frac{1}{x^{n}} =x^{-n}$$ so I don't see why you think this will "become $\frac1x$.

Comment: @Jr.Green Ratio test is a bad approach. Just try to understand what I have written without worrying about $\frac {u_{n+1}} {u_n}$.